# 'Personal' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I just created a new MVC Project and created an empty view. I wrote my first line of code while trying to declare the Model for the view which looks like following:

```
 @model Personal;
```

Where personal is a Model which actually exists. However, it is continuously showing me following error:

> 'Personal' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

I have no idea why something so simple can fail. I wish I could post more code but seriously there is nothing more to it, and I'm not sure why it is failing. I have browsed through some of the SO posts, but not one is having the same error at such a trivial location.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Did you have this view open before creating the model class?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. No I did not have any view open before I created the Model

Comment: You tagged this MVC4 - is that correct? If so, VS2015 doesn't have tooling for MVC4, AFAIK.

Comment: I am sorry it is MVC 5. I just updated the tag in the question

Comment: Have you defined the `@model` in any other view like Layout or a partial view?

Comment: this shouldn't be an issue unless you have some name conflicts - Try using @model <<namespace>>.Personal. Also, if you can provide information about your model. I.e., namespace and the model declaration. that would be helpful

Comment: @Nirman I also tried Model with <NameSpace> it still has the same problem. It is not having any issue recognizing the model. It jus throws the error above.

Comment: The code you have shown would be throwing and  _Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement_ error because of the `;` in `@model Personal;` so you have not show the real code. The error your claiming would be caused if you had used `@model Personal()`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

```
@model <namespace>.Personal
```

**IMPORTANT** : Remove the **semi-colon** from the end of your model declaration.

Comment: Semi-colon! Very important! Struggled much time figuring out what the problem was.. -,- Thanks!

Comment: Shocking ... Microsoft and their intuitiveness

Comment: The error message provided by VS is absolutely useless.

Comment: This is also the solution if the declaration has > at the end

Comment: You deserve more upvotes!

Comment: If I could upvote more times, I would vote for this answer again.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! Looks like another bonehead move by Microsoft. @using requires a ";" semicolon, but @ model doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a comment on the same line as the `@model` statement. Removed the comment and the error went away.

```
@model <namespace>.Model //A comment here can cause the error.
```

**Edit**:

After submitting the above the solution, the error was still there. After trying a few more ideas, I found that the `@using` statements below the `@model` statement also caused the error. I removed the `@using` statements and the error went away. I pasted the `@using` statements back in the same place and everything compiled and ran fine.

Note: Even with the above edit, a comment on the same line as the `@model` statement will still cause this error.